# Get Configuration Data with a Managed Service

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Here is my ConfigUpdater class

```
private final class ConfigUpdater implements ManagedService {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void updated(Dictionary config) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (config == null) {
            return;
        }

        String title = ((String)config.get("title"));

    }
}
```

My question is how can I access String title in any other class? Or how can I get config dictionary in any other class...  Method updated will only be called when a config file is changed... once it is changed how can access its data in other class?

Answer (score 1):

In general you would create a service that exposes these properties to other components.

For example, you could give your ConfigUpdater a second interface. Another component can than lookup/inject this interface from the service registry and use it's methods to access the properties.

I created an example project on GitHub: https://github.com/paulbakker/configuration-example

The most important part is the service that implements both ManagedService and a custom interface:

```
@Component(properties=@Property(name=Constants.SERVICE_PID, value="example.configurationservice"))
public class ConfigurationUpdater implements ManagedService, MyConfiguration{

private volatile String message;

@Override
public void updated(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Dictionary properties) throws ConfigurationException {
    message = (String)properties.get("message");
}

@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
}
```

The configuration can then be used like this:

```
@Component(provides=ExampleConsumer.class,
    properties= {
    @Property(name = CommandProcessor.COMMAND_SCOPE, value = "example"),
    @Property(name = CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION, values = {"showMessage"}) })
public class ExampleConsumer {
    @ServiceDependency
    private volatile MyConfiguration config;

    public void showMessage() {
     String message = config.getMessage();
     System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i am new to OSGI. can you explain this in more derail ?

Comment: I created an example GitHub project: https://github.com/paulbakker/configuration-example